# How to get rotated image with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm using Guillotine JS to manipulate the image rotation, scale, positions, x,y, when user has finish making changes, I use html2canvas to get the final image generated inside a div, in this case my div has a class .frame, so, when user zoom in or out move left right up, down, I do this:

```
html2canvas(target, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) 
    {
    var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    //console.log(data);
    var imgdata = data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
})
```

I have skip a bunch of code this is the only thing I use, with that I get a 64base code for the image inside my div up to this point everything is ok, the generated image is exactly what is need.
The problem is when rotation is apply to the image, for testing I'm using an image with: `width: 1036, height: 615px` inside a div with: `width:676, height:459px`.
This is the generated images
[image: Image with Zoom, pointing to a particular area of the image]

Same as before, different area
[image: same as before, no rotation different area thou]
Same image but this time it has a rotation 180'
[image: Same image but this time it has a rotation]

same image, rotation 90'
[image: same image, rotation 90]

As you can see every time a rotation is use, the result are wrong.
How can I fix that?
I have used Imagemagick to rote and crop the image using guillotine data, the problem here is that the scale is all messup image width * scale only gives 1 x 1px image as a final result, if I hardcode the width and height the result is the same, so I'd love to find a way to fix the rotation with html2canvas.

Comment: where's the code you want help with?

Comment: Would be useful to use an image where the direction is clear. Make an image with a big fat arrow so we can see what's going on, and use that. Also, what's doing the rotation? Guillotine?

Comment: What is Guillotine doing? Letting the user manipulate the HTML, or doing the final canvas rotation, or what? And what about the different stages of the rotation? Does it look right in the HTML, but not in the canvas? A bit of clarity on what's doing what would be helpful.